# How can I save the response as csv without "\n" being displayed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, python-requests

I am having trouble with the output of this script. When the response is returned, the 'details' response has the phrase "\n" throughout. How can I save the response as csv without the "\n"? Thank you for any suggestions.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

def getPrice(url):
    s = HTMLSession()
    r = s.get(url)
    r.html.render(sleep=1)

    product = {
        'title': r.html.xpath('//*[@id="productTitle"]', first=True).text,
        'price': r.html.xpath('//*[@id="priceblock_ourprice"]', first=True).text,
        'details': r.html.xpath('//*[@id="prodDetails"]/div/div[1]/div', first=True).text
    }

    print(product)
    return product

getPrice('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07HXN1V51')
```

traceback

```
{'title': 'Charades Party Game – Speed Charades Board Game – Fast-Paced Party Game - Perfect for Groups and Family Game Nights', 'price': '$24.99', 'details': 'Product Dimensions\n10.25 x 8.5 x 2.6 inches\nItem Weight\n1.75 pounds\nASIN\nB07HXN1V51\nItem model number\n8291\nManufacturer recommended age\n13 years and up\nBest Sellers Rank\n#2,811 in Toys & Games (See Top 100 in Toys & Games)\n#191 in Board Games (Toys & Games)\n\nCustomer Reviews\n/* * Fix for UDP-1061. Average customer reviews has a small extra line on hover * https://omni-grok.amazon.com/xref/src/appgroup/websiteTemplates/retail/SoftlinesDetailPageAssets/udp-intl-lock/src/legacy.css?indexName=WebsiteTemplates#40 */ .noUnderline a:hover { text-decoration: none; }\n4.7 out of 5 stars 682 ratings P.when(\'A\', \'ready\').execute(function(A) { A.declarative(\'acrLink-click-metrics\', \'click\', { "allowLinkDefault" : true }, function(event){ if(window.ue) { ue.count("acrLinkClickCount", (ue.count("acrLinkClickCount") || 0) + 1); } }); }); P.when(\'A\', \'cf\').execute(function(A) { A.declarative(\'acrStarsLink-click-metrics\', \'click\', { "allowLinkDefault" : true }, function(event){ if(window.ue) { ue.count("acrStarsLinkWithPopoverClickCount", (ue.count("acrStarsLinkWithPopoverClickCount") || 0) + 1); } }); });\n\n4.7 out of 5 stars\nIs Discontinued By Manufacturer\nNo\nMfg Recommended age\n13 year and up\nManufacturer\nThe GAME CHEF'}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear: how exactly do you want that response to look like as a csv line?

Comment: @JackFleeting Hi, I want the response to be in a spreadsheet format, with the columns as title, price, details and the data to be in the rows. Does this make sense?

Comment: did you try like this `' '.join(r.html.xpath('//*[@id="prodDetails"]/div/div[1]/div', first=True).text.split())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get rid of the gibberish produced by script and style tags. Moreover, the newline issue has been taken care of. I used `bs4` library in combination with `requests_html` to kick out the unwanted tags.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getPrice(url):
    s = HTMLSession()
    r = s.get(url)
    r.html.render(sleep=1)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.html.raw_html,"html.parser")

    [script.extract() for script in soup.select("script,style")]

    product = {
        'title': soup.select_one('span#productTitle').get_text(strip=True),
        'price': soup.select_one('#priceblock_ourprice').get_text(strip=True),
        'details': ' '.join(soup.select_one('table[class$="prodDetTable"]').text.split())
    }

    return product

print(getPrice('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07HXN1V51'))
```

EDIT:

I'm not sure if this is something what you meant:

```
try:
    title = soup.select_one('span#productTitle').get_text(strip=True)
except AttributeError: title = ''
try:
    price = soup.select_one('#priceblock_ourprice').get_text(strip=True)
except AttributeError: price = ''
try:
    details = ' '.join(soup.select_one('table[class$="prodDetTable"]').text.split())
except AttributeError: details = ''

product = {
    'title': title,
    'price': price,
    'details': details
}
```

Comment: What if one the title, price or details section is not available? How can I implement an else statement?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your dictionary values are simply strings then I would use a replace.

For Example

```py
res = {}
for key in list(product):
    res[key] = product[key].replace('\n',' ')

print(res)
return res
```

More info on replace method:
[image]

Might be able to do your transformation in place, I can't remember if that's allowed for dictionaries.

Edit

For saving as a csv:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(products)
df.to_csv('my_products_csv.csv')
```

Comment: Hi there, the replace script you provided does not replace the new line indicator. Can you provide more explanation please?

Comment: I'm not sure what the data type output is for your `r.html.xpath().text` operation, so you might need to wrap all that in a string conversion, eg `str(r.html.xpath().text)`. Otherwise the replace method is native to string objects in python